# Chord with lyrics - What does it mean if there is an empty space instead of a Chord?

Tags: chords, notation

I have a problem understand what to play on those chords here.

[image]

As you can see from my markings I actually play the `Am` in the first line twice because I kinda feel weird having it only "ring" to the point I play the `G`again. Same with the second line where there is a long pause (by notation) from `Am` to `C`. I wonder what I have to do here? Play `Am` for two bars?.

[image]

I hope I explained what my problem is well enough!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In that sort of notation, you're supposed to keep playing/strumming the chord until told otherwise.

```
C
In this song you play 

the same chord all the way

all the way 

from beginning to end, hooray

all the way
```

Comment: Some notation styles 'remind' you on the next line, but basically you're meant to already know the song & just use this as a quick cheat sheet.

Comment: No chord is very often notated "N.C."

Answer (score 1):

I really hate that way of writing songs out. If you know the song and how it all fits together, then fine. (If you know the song do you actually need anything?!)

But, seriously, it's way too vague. It *doesn't* tell you how many beats or bars (there could be two or more chords in a bar) each symbol represents. And, like you are getting confused with, where in a bar the next line actually starts.

True, as the other answer glibly states, you carry on with the last chord shown until you see a change of chord, then play that. But it just isn't accurate and self-explanatory. I couldn't guarantee that I'd play it correctly from that song shown, and I've got a not bad idea of what I'm doing!

And to make it worse, the chords are often not on exactly the right syllable, and with songs that have a couple of chord changes , say at the end of a verse, there's no way on Earth of telling how long each chord lasts. I'm not sorry to say there's quality to this kind of 'sheet music'. Sadly it's low quality!

Comment: Yeah my problem is with the rythm. I have no idea what pattern I have to hit the strings - especially with those "free" parts. I just make something up that fits into the scheme somehow

Comment: Aside from saying "the other answer is right", this doesn't seem to be an answer - more of a rant.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - thanks for the dv. The other answer is hardly right, and I didn't say it is entirely right. Yes there is some rant there, but that doesn't make it a wrong answer. Tell me you could play sheets like this accurately, given that 'you stay on the same chord till told otherwise'.

Comment: @xetra11 - it's never going to tell you what rhythm pattern to play anyway. No lead sheets ever do. But this doesn't even tell you how long to stay on a chord. Yes, it tells what the next chord is, but not necessarily *when* it comes.

Comment: IMO, the lyrics + chords notation is the perfect tool for many kinds of pop/rock situations. It's an excellent mix of just enough things to get the job done, but not too much to get in the way or be incorrect. Everyone has to know the song to some extent, _listen_ to what happens all the time and react naturally. The notation naturally adjusts to improvised changes, for example if a few extra bars are needed before a verse or chorus. Special riffs and obligatos can be written next to the lyrics with traditional notation. Intros and other instrumental parts can be written as chords + barlines.

Comment: @piiperi - it's the 'everyone has to know the song...' that gets me. I work with the house band at open mics, and this sort of presentation just does not work. I prefer to use nothing (except ears and brain cell) in preference. As far as improvised 'few extra bars' goes - been there too many times with everyone's interpretation of 'a few' to be convinced it works. Most times - it doesn't!

Comment: Then you've been trying to use the notation where you can't make it work well. Don't do that. :) I have so many good things and memories to tell about this notation. For example, I never forget the band who completely recreated or re-imagined a song they didn't know, from a lyrics+chords sheet. Melody and everything. :) It's not for everyone, but nothing is.

Comment: I guess that's what it's good for - re-creating. It's probably the best that could happen. As it's just not a good blueprint to work from as it stands. Horses for courses. My money's *not* on this one! I certainly wouldn't give a student a song written out like that - too many pitfalls.

Comment: @Tim- for the most part I'm in agreement with you as far as giving this kind of chart to a student, but judging by the number of these kinds of sites on the web, I'd have to guess they are quite popular and I wonder if it's not a good idea to teach students what they are up against when they resort to using these papers instead of items that give a more complete picture of the music and what is expected of the performer. That's just my thoughts, for what it's worth. You are a teacher, I am not.

Comment: "*If you know the song...*" fact: not many people know chords just from listening. TBF, I won't call this a "sheet music". This is just a chord reminder, that's all. The player is free to play how they want while using the chord *as a guideline*. The fact that some of them have misaligned chords is disappointing, but it's convenient enough for those who just want **a casual "pick a familiar song and jam"** (imagine "party/karaoke mode"); it's *never* meant to be a learning tool. (Disclaimer: I'm just a hobbyist who likes to transcribe chords from pop/rock songs *by ears*, using Roman numeral.)

Comment: @skinnypeacock - on occasions it has been known! I do it for a laugh. It doesn't take even to the end of a verse usually before the student gives up! Sometimes students bring things like this in, saying they need help understanding how to play it. Often I can't help...

Comment: @AndrewT. - fact: not many people... It's the way they've learned. By learning one song at a time, learning the sequence of chords. I play with players like this, and it's sometimes hard work. If they forget a chord, it all falls apart. If they actually understood what the chords did, it wouldn't happen. They'd also be able to play songs in other keys. That's what 'learning by rote' does.

Comment: At last, someone else who shares my frustration with this type of notation!  In fact, for my own use, I've developed a hybrid notation, adding barlines and wrapping and stretching/squashing the text to match the barlines instead of vice versa — I find that _so_ much easier to play from.  (IME, if I know a song well enough to play from the notation in this question, then I know it well enough to play without any notation at all…)

Comment: This youtube video sums up the attitude in your answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQvXTRKvt5A

Comment: @AnteroDuarte - thanks for the thought. That video is built on someone hearing 3 seconds of Blues. My 'rant' is built on years of seeing the sort of 'sheet music' in the question. If I'm elitist, it's because I've found out generally what works and what does not work. Hence what's contained in my answer - which obviously hit a couple of nerves - but also was agreed with. If that sort of 'sheet music' works for someone, who am I to say 'don't use it'? However, there is a plethora of far superior, effective ways in which to set out words and chords.

Comment: "play sheets like this accurately": of course you can't use these things without knowing the song.  They do not convey any information about melody, meter, or rhythm.  A traditional lead sheet has melody and meter, but still leaves the rhythm of the accompaniment to the player.  But none of that is relevant to the question.  This sort of notation obviously has its uses, ot people wouldn't be using it, and the fact that you find it so vexing just suggests that you're asking it to fulfill a role for which it is not designed.

Comment: @phoog - you're probably right. I just think that if someone is going to the trouble of prviding something to play from - the singing is o.k. with the words - they could do it a  bit more clearly. It may well work for those who know the song, but if they know it and can play, why bother with the chords, and for anyone who doesn't know it too well, it falls short. And people use it because it's readily available for little or no cost. That's all!

Comment: @Tim I suspect that this form arose because it's the easiest way to communicate chords in a text-only medium (i.e., computers).  Come to think of it, I have only seen it on the web.